# what is mean by widget and explain use widget

Tags: java, android, widget

hi i am fresher now i am working android application...tell me how to create widget....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A widget is a small graphical element that can be placed on the "desktop" of an Android device.

Clocks and search inputs are popular widgets.

You can create your own, just read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets

Comment: if i create one video widget....can i see video in that widget....its possible.....

Comment: good question, but please ask it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask